# How to send a string along with NSNotification?

Tags: objective-c, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, nsnotification

I'm trying to write a plugin for phonegap/cordova that allows audio to resume when interrupted by a phone call. I'm using AVAudioSesionInterruptionNotification and it is working well. However, I need to be able to send a string to my event handler, but I can't figure out how.

I'm setting up an event listener here and calling it from the javascript layer:

```
- (void) startListeningForAudioSessionEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
     NSString* myImportantString = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAudioSessionEvent:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
}
```

and I'm handling the event here:

```
- (void) onAudioSessionEvent:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded]]){        
        //do stuff using myImportantString
    }
}
```

can't figure out how to pass myImportantString over to onAudioSessionEvent. I know very little Objective-C (hence my use of cordova), so please respond as if you're talking to a child. Thanks!

By the way, I'm simply trying to add a couple of methods on top of cordova's media plugin found here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/tree/master/src/ios

so the code above is the entirety of my .m file minus this part

`@implementation CDVSound (extendedCDVSound)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to use the block-based API for adding an observer:

```
- (void) startListeningForAudioSessionEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
    NSString* myImportantString = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    id observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                                                    object:nil
                                                                     queue:nil
                                                                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
        if([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded]]){        
            //do stuff using myImportantString; you could even skip the use of that
            //temporary variable and directly use [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0],
            //assuming that command and command.arguments are immutable so that you
            //can rely on them still being the same
        }
    }];
}
```

By using the block-based API, you can directly reference any variables that are in scope at the time the observer is added in the code which is invoked when the notification is posted.

When you're done observing, you need to remove `observer` as an observer of the notification.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: In this particular case, I see no opportunity for retain cycles. Neither `myImportantString` nor `command.arguments` are `self` or instance variables which would involve implicit access to `self`. So, the block doesn't reference `self` and doesn't retain `self`. That, of course, depends on the specific code involved in "`do stuff`". In any case, the cycle would be broken when the observation is removed. So, if you arrange to do that at a point before (and not depending on) `-dealloc`, you're fine.

Comment: With regular notifications you remove the observer in dealloc though? But if NSNotificationCenter is retaining the block, and the block refers to self (seems likely... we don't know what code he's using) then presumably self will be accessed, dealloc will never be called so the notification is never removed. I agree this is probably the best choice depending what he's trying to do, however retain cycles are a problem. A retain cycle involving a view controllers will almost certainly trigger out of memory crashes later.

Comment: Thanks Ken, but I'm getting this error:

`error: parameter name omitted                                                                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *){`

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, it's not necessarily true that "[w]ith regular notifications you remove the observer in dealloc". That's the *latest* you can remove the observer. You really should remove it before then. In any case, if the block code does end up referencing `self` and you have no opportunity to remove the observer prior to `-dealloc`, then you take the ordinary precautions against retain cycles, with a weak reference to self, etc. That's not particular to this case.

Comment: @dadThrowsBolts, sorry about that. I've edited my answer to fix it.

Comment: It works! Thank you!
@KenThomases when and how do i remove the observer?

Comment: You remove it when you're no longer interested in receiving the `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` notification. I don't know when that would be. It depends on the rest of your program logic. You remove it by calling `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer]`, where `observer` is the value that was returned from adding it. That may mean you have to store it in an instance variable rather than a local.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
// near the top of MyController.m (above @implementation)
@interface  MyController ()

@property NSString *myImportantString;

@end

// inside the implementation
- (void) startListeningForAudioSessionEvent:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
     self.myImportantString = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAudioSessionEvent:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) onAudioSessionEvent:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded]]){        
        //do stuff using self.myImportantString
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. However. I got the following error:
 error: cannot find interface declaration for 'MyController'

Comment: @dadThrowsBolts MyController needs to be the name of your controller class. I don't know what that is.

Comment: I don't know what it is either :/
I went back and added some details about where my code is going in the original post if it helps. Thanks again!